# confusion about conditional expectation from Steven financial math textbook

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

**Why it is true from step 1 to step 2? How could i use condition of $Z$ just like that? By using tower rule?
Thank you in advance.**

[image]

Comment: Google: Law of total expectation

Comment: Thank you, just realized i can use this law.